# Add multiple timestamps together from mysql db then get hours and minutes

Tags: php, mysql, database, addition, timestamp

What's the best way to retrieve start_time and end_time times from a mysql db using php and add them together to get a total of hours and minutes? An example military time in my db is: 18:35:19 to 22:05:14. Is it easier with standard or military time? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would summing up ("adding together") a start and end time make any sense? Or do you want to calculate the duration? Also I am not sure what "military time" should be.

Comment: My logic on this may not make any sense to you, but my hope is, is that you can make some sense out of it and make an example that may lead me in the right direction. A customer logs in, now i have the start time and today's date, they logout, now i have end_time. Now i need to add all up all the hours and minutes together plus i need only the data that will pertain to today, week, month and year on that customer.

Comment: In that context, adding the times still doesn't make sense. You sound like you're looking for time elapsed between start_time and end_time. Is that it?

Comment: yes sir, i have this function called getRangeTime(). Its too long to send in this comment, but anyway, first thing i need to do is get the time elapsed from multiple start and end times, then add those up to get the hours and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Carlos,

Some further information such format the data is stored within mysql would have been helpful, as there are certain mysql queries to help with this. But seeing as you've tagged PHP, I would do the following in php:

- convert the time to unixtimestamp using something like mktime (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

  $unixtimestamp_start = mktime($hour,$minute,$second,$month,$day,$year);

  $unixtimestamp_finish = mktime($hour,$minute,$second,$month,$day,$year);
- minus the start time from the finish time.

  $timeDiffSeconds = $unixtimestamp_finish - $unixtimestamp_start;

You now have the amount of seconds between finish and start.

- you can divide that by 60 to have minutes

  $timeDiffMins = $timeDiffSeconds/60;
- you can divide that by 60 again to have hours.

  $timeDiffHrs = $timediffMin/60;